# Gravity Forms, send notifications based on Date

Tags: wordpress, forms, date, gravity-forms-plugin

I would like to send out a Notification based on today's date compared to a date field in my form but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

My current form has these fields: Name, Email, Upload File, and Payment Date.  I would like to send the customer a notification when the Payment Date entered in the form, is two weeks away from today's date.  So if I enter the date January 30th in the form, the Notification will be sent whenever January 16th rolls around. Whatever I do would have to check each entry daily to see if its within that 2 week window.  Thoughts?

Comment: 2 years and nothing.  Seems like it should be built in, or at the very least, a 3rd party solution.